# Protostar: 3 module position horizontally above and below content

Tags: module-display

I'm trying for Joomla Protostar template to create 3 custom module positions above and below the content area.

I have added the positions to the templateDetails.xml.
And I figured that I then have to add the positions into the index.php.

Around line 180 I have this section:

```
        <main id="content" role="main" class="<?php echo $span; ?>">
            <!-- Begin Content -->
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-3" style="xhtml" />
            <jdoc:include type="message" />
            <jdoc:include type="component" />
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-2" style="none" />
            <!-- End Content -->
        </main>
```

And then if I'm right, my code for my Top positions will go before "message" and bottom after "component", using?

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-4" style="xhtml" />
```

but not sure how to do this correctly?

My custom positions Bottom A-B-C and Top A-B-C needs to be horizontally in 3 columns and fill 100% of the main sections width.

For example, if I place a module only on Bottom-A, then that module will fill 100% of the width (same width as position-2). If I place a module on e.g. Bottom A and B they are to be 50/50. If I place a module on Bottom A, B and C they will be 1/3 of the width each (like on position image below)

Had  a look at this thread: [how to make custom positions stack horizontally rather than vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037132/joomla-3-x-protostar-how-to-make-custom-positions-stack-horizontally-rather-th)

With a little modification by the code given in that thread, did give me 3 horizontal positions, but they weren't correctly aligned with e.g position-2 and didn't function according to my wishes.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="bottom-a">
        <?php if ($this->countModules('position-9')) : ?>
             <!--custom position 9 'Bottom-A' -->
            <div id="top-2a" class="span3">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-9" style="xhtml" />
            </div>
             <!-- End Sidebar -->
            <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-b">
        <?php if ($this->countModules('position-10')) : ?>
        <!--custom position 10 'Bottom-B' -->
            <div id="top-2b" class="span3">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-10" style="xhtml" />
            </div>
        <!-- End Sidebar -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-c">
        <?php if ($this->countModules('position-11')) : ?>
        <!--custom position 11 'Bottom-C' -->
            <div id="top-2c" class="span3">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-11" style="xhtml" />
            </div>
        <!-- End Sidebar -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: `but they weren't correctly aligned with e.g position-2 and didn't function according to my wishes.` >>> How were they not correctly aligned? How did they not function?

Comment: Have added a screenshot of my code's results. The Bottom raw is slightly offset to the left and don't fill the entire width. and if I unpublish one of them, the 2 remaining don't expand filling 50/50 of the width.

Comment: I've been looking at this the wrong way. Maths question for you...what's **12 ÷ 3** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Explanation:

Lets looks at what we know:

- Bootstrap is a 12 column grid framework
- You're trying to implement 3 boxes, divided equally in a row

---

```
<------------------------span12------------------------>
<------span4------><------span4------><-----span4------>
<----span3---><----span3---><----span3---><----span3--->
```

#### 12 ÷ 3 = 4

---

## Solution:

Use `span4` instead of `span3`

Comment: Right thanks, that worked fine for using 3 boxes. But my code doesn't seem to make the row flexible. Like if you should happen to only use 2 boxes, those two boxes would be devided 50/50. If only 1, then 100%. But that might be a little more complicated to do i guess?

Comment: Not all all. Have a look at the default Protostar template index.php file. There are some `if ... else` conditions for `$span` sizes